# Linking to a shared object library (.so) when cross-compiling

Tags: android, c, linux, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I am trying to link my c-program to a shared object library (libfoo.so) using the ARM cross-compiler ***arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc***. I am compiling on a Ubuntu system, and I want to run the program on an Android device. The compiling works, but when I try to run the program on my android device I get an error.

I've created a simple test program containing the following files:

**foo.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(void){ puts("Hello, I am a shared library"); }
```

**foo.h**:

```
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__
extern void foo(void);
#endif
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main(void)
{
    puts("This is a shared library test...");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I have then created the shared object library using:
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -fPIC foo.c`
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o`

I then compile my program using: 
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/home/foo -o test main.c -lfoo`

After uploading the test-program to the Android device using adb, I am not able to run it. Instead I get the error: 
`/system/bin/sh: ./test: No such file or directory`
I am in the right directory and the test-file is present, so I assume that it is the shared library that cannot be found. I've tried uploading libfoo.so to the android device as well (to the same path as specified when compiling), but it still doesn't work to run the program.

I've gotten it to work with a static library (foo.o) using *arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o test main.c foo.o*, but not with a shared library.

How do I properly link a shared library when cross-compiling, to make sure that the program can then run on an Android device?

Comment: I tried using -fPIC instead of -fpic. Still can't run ./test. I'll update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Make sure to try the commands: `file test` and `ldd test` for more details (where test is your compiled executable).

Answer (score 1):

The linker isn't able to dynamically link to the library.

Define LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the library:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/foo
```

Comment: I tried to do this on both the Ubuntu system and the Android system and I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right location of the library? Try moving it to your cwd, and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the path is correct. I did try moving the library to the cwd and exporting a new LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Still no luck.. I also tried putting the library in /vendor/lib location where a bunch of other .so files are.
Maybe the error `./test: No such file or directory` refers to something else...? I just can't see how it can't find the shared library, unless it is completely ignoring what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to.

Comment: Try to compile in a different order: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c -o test -L/home/foo -lfoo

Comment: I had finally manage to try it as well, and I encountered the same issue! This is very weird. Did you manage to solve it somehow? when I compile the library from within my raspi it works fine. same exec, same format, same size...

Comment: Yes indeed, its very strange. I did not get it to work, so I ended up switching to using ndk-build instead.